# How to add multi level authentication for point to site Azure VPN Connection

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

Currently we are using point to site azure VPN solution to connection to Azure resource group.

How can we add one more level of authentication like (username / password) or any other authentication before connecting to Resource Group VMs.

Let me know if more information is required

Thanks

Comment: Folks any updates please

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/819216/azure-point-to-site-vpn-with-password-or-2-factor-authentication

Answer (score -2):

MFA is not supported with Azure P2S. It is on the roadmap, but not immediate.
We will consider authentication with customer domain controller first.

Thanks,
Bridget